# Angular 7 service file not keeping variable state

Tags: angular, typescript, service, nativescript, angular7

I have 2 components and 1 service file, 
There is a login component and a dashboard component.

This is my login component, it subscribes to a http request in the service file. When I console log `this.userService.user` it returns correctly. When I route to `dashboard` and log the `this.userService.user` inside the dashboard component its undefined.

```
import { Component, OnInit } from "@angular/core";
import { RouterExtensions } from "nativescript-angular/router";
import { UserService } from "../../shared/services.module";

@Component({
    selector: "login",
    moduleId: module.id,
    templateUrl: "./login.component.html",
    styleUrls: ["./login.css"],
})
export class LoginComponent implements OnInit {
    email: string;
    password: string;

    constructor(private router: RouterExtensions, private userService: UserService) { }

    signUp() {
      this.userService.login(this.email, this.password)
      .subscribe(res => {
          console.log(this.userService.user)
          this.router.navigate(["/dashboard"], { clearHistory: true, animated: false });
      });
    }

    ngOnInit(): void {
    }
}
```

This is my dashboard component, when I log `this.userService.user` its undefined.

```
import { Component, OnInit, Input } from "@angular/core";
import { RouterExtensions } from "nativescript-angular/router";
import { UserService } from "../../shared/services.module";

@Component({
    selector: "dashboard",
    moduleId: module.id,
    templateUrl: "./dashboard.component.html",
    styleUrls: ["./dashboard.css"],
})
export class DashboardComponent implements OnInit {
    constructor(private router: RouterExtensions, private userService: UserService) {
   }

    ngOnInit(): void {
      console.log(this.userService.user)
      console.log(this.userService.getUserName())
    }
}
```

this is my service file

```
import { Injectable } from "@angular/core";
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { HttpHeaders } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Config } from "../config";
import { catchError } from 'rxjs/operators';
import { map, delay, retryWhen, take } from 'rxjs/operators';
import { HttpErrorHandler, HandleError } from '../../http-error-handler.service';
import { User } from '../../models/user/user'

const httpOptions = {
  headers: new HttpHeaders({
    'Content-Type':  'application/json',
  })
};
@Injectable()
export class UserService {
  user: any;
  private handleError: HandleError;

  constructor(private http: HttpClient, httpErrorHandler: HttpErrorHandler) {
    this.handleError = httpErrorHandler.createHandleError('HeroesService');
  }

  getUserName() {
    console.log("return name");
    console.log(this.user)
    if (!this.user) {
      return "failed";
    }
    console.log(this.user.name)
    return this.user.name
  }

  login(email, password) {
    let data = JSON.stringify({'email': email,'password': password})
    return this.http.post(Config.userUrl + 'login', data, httpOptions)
    .map((res: any) => {
      let u = res.user
      this.user = new User(u.name, u.email)
      console.log(this.user)
      return res
    })
    .pipe(
      catchError(this.handleError('login', null))
    );
  }
}
```

It's strange that when I even use a helper function like `getUserName` to just return the name its still undefined even in the service file.

Any idea why it's returning undefined? Any help would be greatly appreciated.
Thanks

Comment: Make sure you have `UserService` in `providers` array inside module.

Comment: Alternative to what @Oen44 said, change `@Injectable()` to `@Injectable({
providedIn: 'root' })` on top of your service. It's the preferred way in recent Angular versions to have your service injectable everywhere (as a singleton).

Comment: @Oen44 yup, `UserService` is in my `app.module.ts`

Comment: @Jeto thanks for the advice, ill be doing that from now on, unfortunately I am still getting `undefined`

Comment: @Matt Could you try and make a (minimal) [StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/fork/angular) reproducing the issue?

Comment: Also you seem to be using NativeScript (added it as a tag to your question) so there might be some specificities to it, especially the `Router` implementation.

Comment: @Jeto yeah, I'm starting to think it may have to do with NativeScript.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

**Module where are you providing the service**

```
@NgModule({
    imports: [
        ...
    ],
    declarations: [
        ...
    ],
    providers: [
        ... // You have propably there the service that you want to provide globally, remove it
    ]
})
export class YourModule {
    static forRoot(): ModuleWithProviders {
        return {
            ngModule: YourModule, // name of this module
            providers: [ YourService ] // put there the service, that you want to provide globally
        };
    }
}
```

**app.module.ts**

```
@NgModule({
    declarations: [
        AppComponent,
        ...
    ],
    imports: [
        ...
        YourModule.forRoot() // add this
    ],
    providers: [
        ...
    ],
    bootstrap: [ 
        AppComponent 
    ]
})
export class AppModule {
}
```

**Service that you want to provide globally**

```
@Injectable() // remove the "providedIn: ..." if you have it there
export class YourService {
    ...
}
```

**Components**

```
@Component({
    selector: "dashboard",
    moduleId: module.id, // remove this line
    templateUrl: "./dashboard.component.html",
    styleUrls: ["./dashboard.css"],
})
export class DashboardComponent implements OnInit {
     ...
}
```

And dont forget to import`YourModule` into the `imports` of the module where you want to use `YourService`.

Answer (score 1):

I thought when you declare like this

`@Injectable({providedIn:'root'})`

it is available to the entire application

Comment: No it's not, it is available only in the module scope,